# Using JUnit @Rule with ScalaTest (e.g. TemporaryFolder)

Tags: scala, unit-testing, junit, scalatest

I would like to be able to use JUnit rules such as `TemporaryFolder` or other `TestRule`s we have already developed in-house.
  What is the best method to accomplish that? I'm aware of JUnitSuite but it doesn't seem to pick up the `@Rule` annotation.
I would like to use a different ScalaTest suite anyway.

So my questions are:

- Are JUnit rules supported by a ScalaTest suit?
- If not, is there a library out there which would make using Junit `TestRule`s possible?
- If not, how to use JUnit `TestRule`s in Scala tests?
- Or is there a more appropriate Scala-specific approach for acomplishing what `TemporaryFolder`, or, e.g., Stefan Birkner's [System Rules](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/system-rules) provide?

---

Here's what I tried with `JUnitSuite`:

```
class MyTest extends JUnitSuite {
  //@Rule
  //val temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder() // throws java.lang.Exception: The @Rule 'temporaryFolder' must be public.

  @Rule
  def temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder()

  @Test
  def test: Unit = {
    assert(temporaryFolder.newFile() !== null) // java.lang.IllegalStateException: the temporary folder has not yet been created
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could solve the problem by creating a member field of type `TemporaryFolder` and returning this field value by the `@Rule` function.

```scala
class MyTest extends JUnitSuite {

  val _temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder

  @Rule
  def temporaryFolder = _temporaryFolder

  @Test
  def test: Unit = {
    assert(temporaryFolder.newFile() !== null)
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, that works :). Missed creation of multiple `TemporaryFolder` instances. In the end, we went with the stackable mixins solution so that we art not locked with JUnitSuite. But anyway, good to know that `@Rule` can be supported in scalatest.

Comment: Glad that I could help :-)

Answer (score 11):

Here is what I came up based on ScalaTest's [documentation on fixtures](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures). Still, I would like to know if there is a better solution.

1. Loan-fixture method

   ```
   class LoanFixtureTest extends FunSuite {
     def withRule[T <: TestRule](rule: T)(testCode: T => Any): Unit = {
       rule(
         new Statement() {
           override def evaluate(): Unit = testCode(rule)
         },
         Description.createSuiteDescription("JUnit rule wrapper")
       ).evaluate()
     }

     test("my test") {
       withRule(new TemporaryFolder()) { temporaryFolder =>
         assert(temporaryFolder.newFile() !== null)
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   - Pros: allows applying the rule only to tests where it is needed
   - Cons: not very elegant usage; clumsy when multiple TestRules are required
2. Using stackable mixins with `withFixture(test: NoArgTest)` override

   ```
   trait TemporaryFolderFixture1 extends SuiteMixin {
     this: Suite =>
     val temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder

     abstract override def withFixture(test: NoArgTest) = {
       var outcome: Outcome = null
       val statementBody = () => outcome = super.withFixture(test)
       temporaryFolder(
         new Statement() {
           override def evaluate(): Unit = statementBody()
         },
         Description.createSuiteDescription("JUnit rule wrapper")
       ).evaluate()
       outcome
     }
   }

   class StackableTraitFixtureTest extends FunSuite with TemporaryFolderFixture1 {
     test("my test") {
       assert(temporaryFolder.newFile() !== null)
     }
   }
   ```

   - Pros: very simple usage, conveniently allows mixing multiple rules in
   - Cons: requires having a mixin for every rule; rules need to be invoked even for tests that don't need them; rule cannot be used e.g. in `BeforeAfterEach#beforeEach()`
3. Overriding `withFixture(test: OneArgTest)`

   ```
   trait TemporaryFolderFixture2 {
     thisFixture: org.scalatest.fixture.FunSuite =>
     type FixtureParam = TemporaryFolder

     override protected def withFixture(test: OneArgTest): Outcome = {
       val temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder()
       var outcome: Outcome = null
       temporaryFolder(
         new Statement() {
           override def evaluate(): Unit = {
             outcome = withFixture(test.toNoArgTest(temporaryFolder))
           }
         },
         Description.createSuiteDescription("JUnit rule wrapper")
       ).evaluate()
       outcome
     }
   }

   class OneArgWithFixtureTest extends org.scalatest.fixture.FunSuite with TemporaryFolderFixture2 {
     test("my test") { temporaryFolder =>
       assert(temporaryFolder.newFile() !== null)
     }
   }
   ```

   - Cons: allows only one TestRule, making in generic to work with any rule instead of just TestRule would require an extra effort

Which one do you like the best?

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me. Based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24455385/1996639). So annotation will be applied to
to the (synthetic) getter method

```
import org.junit._
import scala.annotation.meta.getter

class MyTest extends JUnitSuite {

  @(Rule @getter)
  val tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder

}
```

Just make sure to use junit version >4.11.