# ScalaTest equivalent of JUnit Rule temporary folder?

Tags: scala, scalatest

Does ScalaTest include a fixture similar to the JUnit Rule temporary folder? If not, is there a commonly-used ScalaTest extension library that includes a fixture like that?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a duplicate question of [Using JUnit @Rule with ScalaTest (e.g. TemporaryFolder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160549/using-junit-rule-with-scalatest-e-g-temporaryfolder)

And if it's possible in other frameworks? In my project we use Specs2 and we have autogenerated folders for test-cases. So I know it's possible for Specs2.

Comment: That question is asking how to use JUnit Rules with ScalaTest, whereas I am asking what is the equivalent in ScalaTest.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that's not the same question. Being able to use it in ScalaTest would be equivalent? But ok, let's see if someone else answers. Because to me that question seemed to have good answers already.

Comment: It’s different is that I am looking for something made FOR ScalaTest as opposed to how to adapt something that was not made for it.