# Scala test error: The @Rule must be public

Tags: scala, testing, junit, field, rules

I'm familiar with the necessity of Java unit tests making their @Rule properties public, however new to doing this in Scala. I understand that Scala classes have properties public by default, so expect this to be acceptable:

```scala
class MyTest {

  @Rule
  var failure: ExpectedException = ExpectedException.none()

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Okay, I'm in the middle of reading down https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160549/using-junit-rule-with-scalatest-e-g-temporaryfolder which indicates that @Rule cannot be used in this way at all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be resolved by creating a member field of type `ExpectedException` and returning this field value by the `@Rule` function.

```scala
class MyTest {

  val _failure: ExpectedException = ExpectedException.none()

  @Rule
  def failure: ExpectedException = _failure

}
```