# Using scala wildcards for a typed class

Tags: scala, wildcard

This may be a very stupid question, but as I'll try it anyway. I'm trying to use wildcards with a typed class so I can get the properties of it.

I am trying to provide a sintax (DSL-like) to create objects that would treat the incoming message accordingly to it's type parametrization .
I'd really like the sintax looks something like this:

```
// Types of message
trait TypeMessage
case class TypeMessage1 extends TypeMessage{
    val a : String,
    val b : Int
}
case class TypeMessage2 extends TypeMessage{
    val c : Double,
    val d : String
}

// Here is the problem
class TreatMsg[T <: TypeMessage] {
    // I'm using a random sintax here, just for ilustration
    def getParamInfo( variable : ?? ) = { 
        println("name: " + variable.name + "  value: " + variable.val + "  type: " + variable.val.getClass)
    }
}
object TreatMsg{
    def apply[T <: TypeMessage] = new TreatMsg[T]
}


// Creating actors
TreatMsg[TypeMessage1].getParamInfo(_.a)
TreatMsg[TypeMessage2].getParamInfo(_.d)
```

So, how to get this wildcard working? I mean, I'd like that the "getParamInfo()" function accepts only properties from the class passed to TreatMsg.
I have a solution that uses [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589603/scala-set-a-field-value-reflectively-from-field-name), but I'd like to get rid of this reflection.
Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Inheriting from case classes is deprecated. You could use a trait for CClass1 instead.

Comment: From which *value* do you want to use `_.c`? You only give a type.

Comment: Actually, just want to get the name of "c" here, but I was wondering if it could be possible to use a sintaxe like this one that I mentioned.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. Could you add some more code maybe. Eg. what should `useVariable` return. Currently, it is not clear what the function `_.c` should be called with, so I don’t think this syntax is going to work without changes.

Comment: I changed the example to try clarify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def useVariable[RetVal](func: (T)=>RetVal) = //...
```

Comment: Now that you've clarifed your question, it's obvious that there's now way to get `variable.name` as you've specified in your example. The solution you're looking for is probably to pass a string to `useVariable` and use reflection to get its value.

Comment: Yes, that's it. But the approach you suggested does fit well to my complete use-case with some small changes. Thank you Ken